# How to implement timespec accumulators?

Tags: c, linux, time

In a program that accumulates `struct timespec` deltas, I am doing the following logic:

```
struct timespec accu, start, stop;

for (...) {
    // record start
    // perform some logic
    // record stop

    accu.tv_sec += stop.tv_sec - start.tv_sec;
    accu.tv_nsec += stop.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec;
    if (accu.tv_nsec >= 1000000000L) {
        accu.tv_nsec -= 1000000000L;
        ++accu.tv_sec;
    }
} // end for loop
```

However, when I print the result using:

```
printf("%lld.%.9ld\n", (long long) accu.tv_sec, accu.tv_nsec);
```

I sometime see results like: 1.-611075708

What am I doing wrong to have a negative value in `accu.tv_nsec`?

Note: `start` & `stop` retrieved with `clock_gettime()`.

Comment: Think about what happens when `stop.tv_nsec < start.tv_nsec`. You get a negative value which you accumulate into the accumulator. If this negative accumuland drops the accumulator below zero, it's of course not going to be `>= 1000000000L`. You also need the wraparound logic in the other direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convert `struct timespec` to a `uint64_t` number of nanoseconds since epoch and take deltas between those and accumulate them easily. E.g.:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdint.h>

inline uint64_t as_nanoseconds(struct timespec* ts) {
    return ts->tv_sec * (uint64_t)1000000000L + ts->tv_nsec;
}

int main() {
    struct timespec start, stop;
    uint64_t accu_nsec = 0;

    for (...) {
        // record start
        // perform some logic
        // record stop

        accu_nsec += as_nanoseconds(&stop) - as_nanoseconds(&start);
    } // end for loop
}
```

Comment: Answer accepted, thanks, however I will rather use:
`accu += (stop.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * 1000000000L + stop.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec;` which will save one arithmetic operation per accumulation.

Comment: Be careful to always cast the result of (stop.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) into a 64-bit int, otherwise the compiler might do a 32-bit int, and when you multiply by 1000000000 you will overflow.

Comment: @PatrickAllaert It depends on the compiler, clang generates same code for both versions: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/13ajxY

Answer (score 3):

You can't simply add the times like this without proper overflow/underflow handling of the second addition. Example: start = 1.99...s, stop = 2.01...s

This gives us:

```
accu.tv_sec += 2 - 1 = 1;
accu.tv_nsec += 01... - 99.. = -98...;
```

Therefore, you have to use a temporary variable to calculate `nsec`. If it's <0, then you need to substract 1s and add `1000000000L` to nsec.